# script to verify running services on specific ports

Tags: shell-script, regular-expression, string, netstat

I got a task to do.

I have to search whether, are there running services on below ports.
ports 53 & 55
If not I have to send alerts.
Please correct my logic and syntax in below code for one port

```
ntstat=`netstat -tulpn | grep :53 | grep LISTEN | awk {'print $4'}`
port="*:53"

#Just to echo for testing
echo $ntstat  
echo $port

if [[ "$ntstat" == "$port" ]];
then
   echo " X Service at port number $port"
else 
   echo " Port is not listing  "
fi
```

---

Output :

```
127.0.1.1:53
*:53
Port is not listing
```

I am struggling to match strings (127.0.1.1:53 to *:53)

Comment: @Kusalananda please look into this

Comment: You've got some answers from people on Linux systems. I'm not on Linux and my `netstat` is different. Could you not also check the daemons that are supposed to listen on those ports? Some `systemctl` command or other to make sure they are running? (again, I'm not on Linux)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also do a `text-processing` to your current output to match the port. Just add `sed -e 's/.*:/:/g'`

```
#!/bin/bash
ntstat=`netstat -tulpn | grep ":53 " | grep LISTEN | awk {'print $4'} | sed -e 's/.*:/:/g'`
port=":53 "

#Just to echo for testing
echo $ntstat  
echo $port

if [[ "$ntstat" == "$port" ]]
then
    echo " X Service at port number $port"
else 
    echo " Port is not listing  "
fi
```

Please note that I added a space right after the port number in order to avoid other ports containing `53`

Since this are `bash` operators, you must want to put the shebang `#!/bin/bash` at the very top of your script so when you execute your script as `./portlisten.sh`, it will take the interpreter as `/bin/bash`, would be the same if you execute your script as `$ bash portlisten.sh`

Comment: Thanks lot for your solution . Can please explan how does  sed -e 's/.*:/:/g'  command works with my output 127.0.1.1:53.since i am very new to sed commands .

Comment: I have implemented your code. but still i am getting this out put -             :53
:53
portlisten.sh: 10: portlisten.sh: [[: not found
Port is not listing

Comment: @Prabash I edited the answer, give a try

Comment: so i added your new code and execute as ./portlisten.sh please find output as below  _:53
:53
 Port is not listing_  still it says "port is not listing" , I think we  have problem with string matching

Comment: I am able to below get out put :53
:53
 X Service at port number :53 
#I have removed " " in variables comparison  ..... if [[ $ntstat == $port ]] . Once again thank for your support.

Answer (score 2):

To check if there are running services on ports `53`(or `55`) I would suggest the following optimized solution:

```
port=":53"
if netstat -tulpn | grep --line-buffered -q "$port .*LISTEN"; then
    echo " X Service at port number $port"
else 
    echo " Port is not listing  "
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `netstat` since this is a deprecated command, use `ss` instead.

In your case you could use something like:

```
ss -H -o state listening '( sport = :53 or sport = :55 )'
```

Comment: Who deprecated `netstat`? How can a non-standard utility be deprecated?

Comment: @Kusalananda the `netstat` command is part of the `net-tools` bundle which hasn't been maintained since 2011. To me this is pretty much outdated and shouldn't be used in modern operating systems. Have a loop at the `man netstat` manpage. Once again, `netstat` is replaced by `ss (Socket Statistics)` , has a more sophisticated option set and is the future.

Comment: @val0x00ff Ah, the Linux `netstat` may well be old, but `netstat`, albeit another implementation of it, is also installed by default on BSDs. This is obviously not "deprecated" but actively maintained.

Comment: @Kusalananda BSD implementations use `sockstat` in that regard. Also as far as my research concerns, The man page of `netstat` tells us the following: `NOTES
       This  program  is mostly obsolete.  Replacement for netstat is ss.  Replacement for netstat -r is ip route.  Replacement for net‐
       stat -i is ip -s link.  Replacement for netstat -g is ip maddr.`

Comment: @val0x00ff I'm ok with saying that the net-tools `netstat` may be deprecated, but the BSD version certainly is not: http://man.openbsd.org/netstat

Comment: @Kusalananda oh that's an interesting link. I am a FreeBSD user so I have always used FreeBSD. Obsoleteness of netstat apparently doesn't apply for OpenBSD.

Comment: @val0x00ff Well, the same goes for [the FreeBSD `netstat`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=netstat&sektion=1) (it's based on the same implementation).

Comment: @Kusalananda haven't used `netstat` on FreeBSD mainly because `sockstat` is more intuitive to me. So for *nix based distrubutions `netstat` but also `ifconfig` (also replaced by `ip`) which are part of the `net-tools` package should not be used. That's my point I wanted to make in my answer. I don't think an answer using `netstat` or `ifconfig` for that matter should be considered correct.